# Setting readonly property on editable jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using jQuery editable datatable. I want some of the fields in the table should be non-editable. So I am using class name `readOnly` and define is as follows in CSS:

```
.readOnly {
   readonly: true;
}
```

But the data field not turned to `readonly`: data in that column is editable .

How should I overcome this?

Comment: There is no CSS readonly  property :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class name

```
           class="read_only"
```

this will do the trick.